# Delete/Add ppa in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Using `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` I find the following ppa.

```
ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list
ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list.save
```

I've installed ppa-purge, but am unsure what the command is to use it or if I can overwrite that ppa with this one:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian wily main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian wily main
```

I've tried to remove it with the Software Center, but it still comes up in the ls from above. If I use:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:repository-name/subdirectory
```

what would be the repository-name and the subdirectory?

Comment: What are the contents of `ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list`?

Comment: Then it seems the PPA has already been removed.

Comment: why would it continue to show up in the ls command I use above then? It seems strange that I can still install qgis without it, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:path/name
```

Better an more simple to use, ppa-purge have some problems